# split number on thousand separator in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need to split the number 1.0765453 because I need to separate the km from the meters

The result should be 76 (ignoring the zero)

Can anyone offer a suggesti, please

Thanks, Richard

Comment: @Your edit. The 3rd solution from my answer (the one that truncates) will give you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use string methods first convert to a string:

```
var parts = 1.8765453.toString().split('.');
```

or

```
var parts = (''+1.8765453).split('.');
```

But you should do it like this and work only with numbers, not strings:

```
var distance = 1.8765453; // in Km
var km = Math.floor(distance);
var meters = Math.floor(distance * 1000) % 1000;
```

or, if you want it rounded rather than truncated:

```
var distance = 1.8765453; // in Km
var rounded = Math.round(1.8765453 * 1000);
var km = Math.floor(rounded / 1000);
var meters = rounded % 1000;
```

Comment: I think this is the answer, I never used %, it is modulus,right? I will check this one. just a sec

Comment: `%` a.k.a. `mod`, `modulus`, `remainder` :)

Comment: thanks, that worked, had a bit off a problem, computer cpu running overtime. Al good now.

Answer (score 0):

`indexof` works on strings. Are you sure that you have the number as a string or is it an *actual* decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Math.floor(dist/1)

Comment: I think that was possibly a way to convert to a number? Much like `1*dist` or `+dist`.